# Analogue for mean and spread of 2D lines

Tags: geometry, descriptive-statistics

I have a set of 2D lines (contour lines from a collection of images), and would like to somehow represent them with an "average" and some measure of spread (se figure below). What could be a good way to achieve this? It will only be used for illustrative purposes, so the simpler the better.

[image: 2D lines summary]

Comment: In what sense do you want the center curve to be the center? Minimize the worst case difference between the center curve and any of the curves along vertical lines? Or would you prefer something less sensitive to outliers? The appropriate notion of center will inform the appropriate notion of spread.

Comment: It doesn't really matter that much. But if it had been a 1D case, I would have chosen mean over median, I guess that translates to minimizing the worst case difference?

Comment: The mean minimizes the spread around it in the sense of the standard deviation, so here you want a minimizer of some kind of averaged squared $L^2$ norm of differences, i.e. find $f^*$ to minimize $\sum_i \int |f^*(t) - f_i(t)|^2 dt$ and then draw the width of the band as some appropriate multiple of $\sqrt{\sum_i |f^*(t)-f_i(t)|^2}$.

Comment: But as Loutcho Glotuk alluded to, the difficulty is in getting some kind of synchronized parameterization of the curves. I would probably try starting with an arclength parametrization so that each curve is traversed in one time unit, but I am not sure how well this will work without trying it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to forge parameterizations of each line, i.e. have a real variable $t$ such that $f(i,t)$ is the 2D function that provides the point of line number $i$ at time $t$. Then I would try to synchronize the parameterizations, i.e. try to minimize $|f(i, t) - f(j, t)|$ for all $t$ and for all $i \neq j$... that's the hard part. Then finally, I would say that the average line is parameterized by the average $f(t)$ of the $f(i,t)$. The spread would be at each $t$: $\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n,|f(i,t)-f(t)|^2}$.

Comment: I think you need some kind of norm, I don't think this pointwise procedure is well defined.

Answer (score 0):

Consider (see below) a *polar representation* with a well chosen origin $O$ (depending on the "whirling" of the curves) with rays intersecting the curves in

$$r_1(\theta), r_2(\theta) ... r_n(\theta) \tag{1}$$

(no need to associate a curve to an index).

For a given value of $\theta$ :

- Take the mean for the central curve (example : point $M$ below).
- Take the standard deviation $\sigma$, or a multiple  $a \sigma$, for limiting the gray area to line segment $S_{\theta}=[-a \sigma, a \sigma]$.

The continuity of values in (1) warrants that continuous curves will be generated in the process, as well for the locus of point $P$ as for the endpoints of the intervals $S_{\theta}$.

[image]

Comment: Any comment ?...